# Separate Partitions usage

Tags: linux, partition

I would like to know the benefits & usage of creating separate partitions for different areas like swap,  /, /boot, /home, /var etc. How much size should i assign to them ?

Although i want to install separate /home & / partition since i may need to try different distros. So, creating separate / & /home will be helpful there but do i need to create other partitions separately also ?

Comment: I would look into LVM rather than using separate partitions. It's much more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is generally no benefit to creating further partitions.  Having a separate swap partition used to be the only way to have swap on linux ( a really long time ago ), and the habit still sticks around.  You can use a swap file instead though.  The reason for a separate /boot is if your bios is broken and can not access the entire disk, then you need to have /boot in the early part of the disk where the bios can reach it.  A /var partition is really only useful if for some reason, you want to normally run with your root mounted read only, which is rather unusual these days.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefits and some additional information of partitioning, check out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/516353/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-mounting-various-directories-on-sep